# How do I append text to a /etc/… configuration file in NixOS?

Tags: config, pam, nixos

*[disclosure: I asked about this earlier on the NixOS channel but didn't get an answer after 30 minutes and it's a busy channel. If I get one there, I'll replicate it here]*

I'm trying to add some lines to a configuration file in NixOS (for example `/etc/pam.d/sudo`). The configuration options available in [pam.nix](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/8c86ce707ec555bc2328906a86c83386fea4de4c/nixos/modules/security/pam.nix) do not include the line I want to add (in this case, `account requisite pam_time.so`), and it does not include an `extraConfig` option either.

I know I can create new configuration files using `environement.etc.filename.text` so I went with that, but `sudo nixos-rebuild switch` then complains that it has two sources for the configuration file, the official one and mine (`mismatched duplicate entry /nix/… <-> /nix/…`):

```
environment.etc."pam.d/sudo".text = ''blah'';
```

**Is there a general way to append to a /etc/ configuration file (or to patch it) in NixOS?**

Or is the only way to modify the system .nix files (e.g. modifying `pam.nix`, which I'm reluctant to do as it will collide with future updates)?

Answer (score 5):

You can add lines to the default value of `security.pam.services.sudo.text` using `mkOverride` or the shortcut `mkDefault` to give your value the same priority as the default. You can control the order with `mkOrder` or the shortcuts `mkBefore` and `mkAfter`. So to append, you could do:

```
security.pam.services.sudo.text = pkgs.lib.mkDefault( pkgs.lib.mkAfter "# hi" );
```

When there are multiple values for an option, only the values with the lowest priority are kept. If there are still multiple values, they are sorted and merged. `mkOverride` and `mkOrder` create special values that the code in [modules.nix](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/release-17.09/lib/modules.nix) recognizes when it is doing this. Ordinary values have the default priority (100) and sort order (1000). [pam.nix](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/release-17.09/nixos/modules/security/pam.nix) uses `mkDefault` for the value it creates for the `text` option, which makes the priority 1000, thus ordinary values will replace it instead of being merged.

The [NixOS manual section on Modularity](https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#sec-modularity) explains a bit more.

I don't think you can do this generically for `environment.etc` because the target file doesn't have to match the attribute name, and [pam.nix](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/release-17.09/nixos/modules/security/pam.nix) in particular does not name any of its entries in `environment.etc`. It is more like a list of instructions that are processed in sequence. See [etc.nix](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/release-17.09/nixos/modules/system/etc/etc.nix) and
 [make-etc.sh](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/release-17.09/nixos/modules/system/etc/make-etc.sh)

Answer (score -1):

For the files of `/etc/pam.d/sudo` and other files in the same directory, a simple solution is to use `security.pam.services.sudo.text`, but my current best attempt requires hardcoding the original contents of the file.

```
security.pam.services.sudo.text = ''
existing contents of /etc/pam.d/sudo …
extra lines …
'';
```

Hopefully other answers will come up with a more general-purpose way of altering configuration files (and keeping their original contents).